# Unable to start AMQ broker with persistent store on an NFSv3 share

Tags: activemq-classic

I've been struggling to start AMQ broker node with persistent store on an NFSv3 share.
I keep getting the below error complaining of unavailable locks.
I've made sure that all java processes are killed and the lock file on the shared folder is deleted before starting the AMQ master broker.

When I start AMQ, it seems to create a lock file on the shared folder and after that it complains of unavailable locks.

```
Loading message broker from: xbean:activemq.xml
 INFO | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@73cf56e9: startup date [Mon Dec 23 05:28:23 UTC 2013]; root of context hierarchy
 INFO | PListStore:[/home/pnarayan/apache-activemq-5.9.0/activemq-data/notificationsBroker/tmp_storage] started
 INFO | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/home/y/share/nfs/amqnfs]
 INFO | JMX consoles can connect to service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi
 INFO | Database /home/y/share/nfs/amqnfs/lock is locked... waiting 10 seconds for the database to be unlocked. Reason: java.io.IOException: No locks available
```

Below is the activemq xml configuration file I'm using:

```
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <broker 
        xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
        xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  

    brokerName="notificationsBroker" 
    useJmx="true" 
    start="true" 
    persistent="true" 
    useShutdownHook="false" 
    deleteAllMessagesOnStartup="false">

        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="/home/y/share/nfs/amqnfs" />
        </persistenceAdapter>

        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>

    </broker>
</beans>
```

Is this because of the reason that I'm using NFSv3, but not NFSv4 as recommended by AMQ?

I believe the issue with NFSv3 is that it cannot cleanup the lock if at all the broker process dies abruptly. However it shouldn't be having any issues in starting the broker. If my understanding is right why am I observing the above error?

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right in what you say - NFS3 does not clean up its locks properly. When using KahaDB, the broker creates a file in `$ACTIVEMQ_DATA/lock`. If that file exists, chances are that something has a hold on it (or at least NFS3 thinks that it does) and the broker will be blocked. Check to see whether the file is there, and if so, use the `lsof` command to determine the process id of its holder.